# In ActiveRecord how do I use 'changed' (dirty) in a before_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to set my summary field to a sanitized version of the body field, but only if the user does not supply their own summary ie. params[:document][:summary] is blank.

This appears to work fine if I create a new record, if I enter a summary it is saved, if I don't the body is used to generate the summary.

However when I update the record the summary always gets overridden. From my log files I can see that 'generate_summary' gets called twice, the second time the 'changes' hash is empty.

```
class Document << ActiveRecord::Base
  # Callbacks
  before_save  :generate_summary

private

  def generate_summary
    @counter ||= 1

    logger.debug '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
    logger.debug @counter.to_s
    logger.debug 'changes: ' + self.changes.inspect
    self.summary = Sanitize.clean(self.body).to(255) if self.body && (!self.summary_changed? or self.summary.blank?)
    @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

Log on Update:

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

1

changes: {"summary"=>["asdasdasdasd", "three.co.uk"]}

Page Update (0.7ms)   UPDATE `documents` SET `meta_description` = 'three.co.uk', `summary` = 'three.co.uk', `updated_at` = '2009-09-30 11:37:08' WHERE `id` = 77

SQL (0.6ms)   COMMIT

SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

2

changes: {}

Page Update (0.5ms)   UPDATE `documents` SET `meta_description` = 'asdasdasdasd', `summary` = 'asdasdasdasd', `updated_at` = '2009-09-30 11:37:08' WHERE `id` = 77

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller probably saves twice as said by @nasmorn. You can also check that your body as changed before updating your summary.

```
if self.body_changed? && (!self.summary_changed? or self.summary.blank?)
  self.summary = Sanitize.clean(self.body).to(255)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Only logical explanation is that the controller somehow saves twice.
Is this log from the console  where you call update on the record or is it from a real request that comes through the controller?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `'update_attributes'` triggers the before_save callback, so in my controller `'generate_summary'` is called twice once by `'update_attributes'` and once by `'save'`. This is not expected behaviour.

Checking the body has changed as suggested by @vincent seems to prevent the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Actually it is expected behavior - ActiveRecord follows a strict callback chain when saving to the database and update_attributes explicitly calls save as part of its process. If you merely want to set attributes without saving, use attributes=

Answer (score -1):

The way I bypass the multiple before_save calls is introducing

```
attr_accessor :object_saved
```

and them inside the call back method

```
before_save :before_save_method
```

I do this

```
def before_save_method
  if self.object_saved.nil?
     self.object_saved = true
    # Do Something 
  end
end
```